# convert pdf to image [jpeg|png]

Tags: pdf, conversion, imagemagick, ghostscript

I need to convert pdf files into image files (like: png (prefer), jpeg).

I used `convert` (from the ImageMagick package) but it takes more than 4 seconds for a 2 page pdf file with only tables (something like an invoice), so this pdf is really light. I found out that `convert` uses `gs` to do it. If I do this with `gs`, the result can be of better quality, and rendered faster.

So I have 3 questions:

1. Should I use some specific flags in ghostscript package compilation process to make it work faster?
2. What options for `gs` can help me get png or jpg files faster and with better quality?
3. Where can I find documentation about conversion from pdf to image formats?

Comment: 'If I do this with gs, the result can be of better quality, and rendered faster.' - Do you mean that your `gs` call is as slow or slower than a `convert` call and produces output of lower quality? Btw, I suggest to add two examples, how you called `convert` and `gs`.

Comment: is it possible to resize image with help gs ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can check-out `pdfdraw` from [mupdf](http://www.mupdf.com/) (package `mupdf-tools` under Debian/Debian-derivatives).

From its description:

> pdfdraw  will render a PDF document to image files.  The
>   supported image formats are: pgm, ppm, pam and png.  Select the
>   pages to be rendered by specifying a comma separated list of
>   ranges and individual page numbers for example: 1,5,10-15).  In
>   no pages are specified all the pages will be rendered.

Perhaps it is faster for your use case.

For example `mupdf` (a PDF viewer) is really fast (and consumes very little memory) for a lot of documents I tested it with.

Comment: it's renamed to mudraw